# Visual Studio 2015 - Node - Failure to load json (unexpected token)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

I have a node project in Visual Studio.

[image]

In the app.js, file, when I create the following code, it works as expected

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = '{ "name": "John Doe", "age": 42 }';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(obj);
```

[image]

When I take the json out the app.js file and put it into its own file and load it, it works fine

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('test.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

[image]

However, when I try to load and parse it, I get the following failure:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('test.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(obj);
});
```

[image]

Is there additional configuration I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: Your logic is fine, but you've got a dodgy character at the start of your JSON file. If your JSON file just has `{ "name": "John Doe", "age": 42 }` then your logic works.

Comment: I changed the file from UTF-8 to ASCII encoding and it worked.  So something is up b/c I am specifying UTF-8 in the parameters